# Mongoose upsert duplicate key error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying do an upsert using Mongoose, but I'm getting a duplicate key error for the very key that should trigger the upsert.

Schema:

```
"resource": {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Resource"},                       
"skill": {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Skill"},                             
"level": {type: Number, min: 1, max: 5}

.index({skill: 1, resource: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Then I make the call:

```
    //self is a Resource instance
    ResourceSkillLevel.update({                                           
        resource: self._id,
        skill: skill._id,
        level: level
    }, {$set: {level: level}}, {upsert: true}, cb);
```

If the `(resource, skill)` does not exist, this call works just fine and properly creates the `ResourceSkillLevel` entry.  However, when I call it again I get `duplicate key error index`.  The listed duplicate key is the tuple resource/skill key.  Why isn't it upserting when it finds the duplicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're including `level` in the `update` query criteria parameter, so if that doesn't also match the existing record it will try and create a new doc which will fail the unique index which only spans `skill` and `resource`.

Try changing your `update` to this:

```
ResourceSkillLevel.update({                                           
    resource: self._id,
    skill: skill._id
}, {$set: {level: level}}, {upsert: true}, cb);
```